# Automating Account Disabling in JIRA

Tags: jira

I've been reading some feature request-style threads in [Atlassian's own JIRA install](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-931) on how to disable (not remove) users in JIRA, and their suggested solution involves a series of UI actions.  For the number of users that our organization supports, this needs to be automated with the rest of our employee account provisioning logic.

I've been looking in the JIRA database and found the `membershipbase` table, but simply removing records from here `WHERE USER_NAME="$username"` doesn't seem to have a completely successful outcome.  When I go to the User Browser in the Administration section and look up that user, groups still appear for the user.

Does anyone have any experience with this that could point me in the right direction on any other tables I need to modify?

Thanks in advance,

-aj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at Atlassian's [Crowd](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/). Even if you don't use SSO, it may help you to integrate with your existing infrastructure for handling authentication and authorization (i.e. groups) centrally. It also provides an administrative frontend that is designed for the corresponding tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the [EditUserGroups.setGroupsToLeave()](http://63-246-22-42.contegix.com/jira/4.0.0-rc1/com/atlassian/jira/web/action/admin/user/EditUserGroups.html#setGroupsToLeave(java.lang.String[])) method. As far as I remember, users need to be in the `jira-users` group to log in. So, if you remove this group from the user, it may be effectively what you need (not delete but deactive user acount).

If this does not help, I'd look into the source code of JIRA (which is available for all types of licenses afaik) to see which tables are modified by the above method.

Comment: @mhaller - will take a look at that code tonight to see if it exposes the SQL statements I need...thx.

Comment: @mhaller - I looked at the code and it looks like JIRA just uses com.opensymphony.user not their own implementation.  Unfortunately I don't have time to look at their code also.  Maybe I'll post another question about osuser...